# Desktop DNS resetting to fallback

Tags: networking, dns

Run my own DNS on my network both 22.04 server and desktop for testing and understanding (have done for over 2 decades) and it keeps getting reset to the fallback DNS.

I configure my DNS using netplan (changed the values to protect the innocent)

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        enp5s0:
            addresses: [10.10.1.70/24]
            gateway4: 10.10.1.99
            nameservers:
                    search: [mydomain.local] 
                    addresses: [10.10.1.1]
            dhcp4: yes
```

Originally I fixed this problem by changing /etc/systemd/resolved.conf

```
[Resolve]
DNS=10.10.1.1 8.8.8.8 9.9.9.9
domains=mydomain.local
```

This seemed to work on 20.04 (I could be wrong). Really feel a failure fixing it by typing

```
sudo netplan apply
```

Happy to learn the correct way to configure a DNS now so it is now overwritten. (I am reasonably sure (sound like a politician) that it is not falling back because of network issues.

Love Ubuntu, know it is me, just would like some of that "teach a man to fish" karma

Thanks,